# Java code editor & compiler on iOS iPad

Tags: java, ios, text-editor, programming, compiler

I'm looking for a code editor (compatible with iOS on an iPad) that has the following features:

- Java code editor
- Java code compiler
- Java code is shown neatly (syntax highlighting would be an added bonus)

Like a simpler version of, say, Eclipse or NetBeans, but for iOS. I don't need to export these as jar. Just to enter code and run it temporarily for practice purposes.

Preferably free but up to $5 is ok.

Comment: Please read: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) I agree with Tom that essential details are missing, e.g.: What features do you need? What price would you be willing to pay? Please **[edit]** your question accordingly. Feel free to @ ping me afterwards so I can "take it off hold".

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the software should syntax-highlight and pretty-print Java Source Code, and then also "compile" it (to `.jar` I assume)? No debugging in case of errors? No code folding, or "connecting calls" (i.e. "jump to declaration" and the like)? The title asks for a compiler, the body for an editor – so I assume you're looking for a kind of [Java IDE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[java]+ide+answers%3A1)?

Comment: More like a simpler version of, say, Eclipse or NetBeans, but for iOS. I don't need to export these as jar. Just to enter code and run it temporarily for practice purposes.

Comment: @BorisJakovljević Please make sure the edit reflects your original question, thanks

Comment: It does. Thanks for the edit. I mean - having the question like this is definitely more legible. But wasn't it clear enough from the very start? So many questions are there that do not have the format as I do.

Comment: Wanted to provide a link to this app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pico-compiler-java-code-editor/id992268206?mt=8 I have not used this app, nor do I know any information about it, I just found it while doing a simple google search.